# Is it possible to extract the player's depth pixels only, out of the depth bitmap?

Tags: c#, kinect, pixel, depth

I am new to kinect developing and new to stackoverflow as well! 
Here's my situation:

Having a depth camera, I can get the depth data easily. What I want to do is once I detect there is a person (player) exists in front of the camera, ***I would extract the depth pixels of the player only, and put it onto a transparent background, so that the output is a static image of the depth image of the player only, on a transparent background.***

I would like to ask ***is it possible to do the job***? I've done some research and find some functions may help to do so like SkeletonToDepthImage() or  the depth pixel data (which includes the distance and player index).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you mean that you want to render a silhouette of the player, based on the depth data, showing just their outline.  Is that correct?

The [Kinect for Windows Developer Toolkit](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/kinectforwindows/develop/developer-downloads.aspx) provides multiple examples that does exactly this.  The "green screen" examples show you how to extract the depth data and map it to the color stream to show just the player on a background of choice.  The "Basic Interactions" example has a silhouette example that does exactly what I'm interpreting you to want.

Look over the examples provided by Microsoft to get a good understanding of many of the basic use scenarios for the Kinect.

Based on the silhouette example from the Basic Interactions project, I wrote a silhouette control.  The core of the control is made of the following two functions (i.e., the functions that actually produce the silhouette.

```
private void OnSkeletonFrameReady(object sender, SkeletonFrameReadyEventArgs e)
{
    using (SkeletonFrame skeletonFrame = e.OpenSkeletonFrame())
    {
        if (skeletonFrame != null && skeletonFrame.SkeletonArrayLength > 0)
        {
            if (_skeletons == null || _skeletons.Length != skeletonFrame.SkeletonArrayLength)
            {
                _skeletons = new Skeleton[skeletonFrame.SkeletonArrayLength];
            }

            skeletonFrame.CopySkeletonDataTo(_skeletons);

            // grab the tracked skeleton and set the playerIndex for use pulling
            // the depth data out for the silhouette.
            // TODO: this assumes only a single tracked skeleton, we want to find the
            // closest person out of the tracked skeletons (see above).
            this.playerIndex = -1;
            for (int i = 0; i < _skeletons.Length; i++)
            {
                if (_skeletons[i].TrackingState != SkeletonTrackingState.NotTracked)
                {
                    this.playerIndex = i+1;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

private void OnDepthFrameReady(object sender, DepthImageFrameReadyEventArgs e)
{
    using (DepthImageFrame depthFrame = e.OpenDepthImageFrame())
    {
        if (depthFrame != null)
        {
            // check if the format has changed.
            bool haveNewFormat = this.lastImageFormat != depthFrame.Format;

            if (haveNewFormat)
            {
                this.pixelData = new short[depthFrame.PixelDataLength];
                this.depthFrame32 = new byte[depthFrame.Width * depthFrame.Height * Bgra32BytesPerPixel];
                this.convertedDepthBits = new byte[this.depthFrame32.Length];
            }

            depthFrame.CopyPixelDataTo(this.pixelData);

            for (int i16 = 0, i32 = 0; i16 < pixelData.Length && i32 < depthFrame32.Length; i16++, i32 += 4)
            {
                int player = pixelData[i16] & DepthImageFrame.PlayerIndexBitmask;
                if (player == this.playerIndex)
                {
                    convertedDepthBits[i32 + RedIndex] = 0x44;
                    convertedDepthBits[i32 + GreenIndex] = 0x23;
                    convertedDepthBits[i32 + BlueIndex] = 0x59;
                    convertedDepthBits[i32 + 3] = 0x66;
                }
                else if (player > 0)
                {
                    convertedDepthBits[i32 + RedIndex] = 0xBC;
                    convertedDepthBits[i32 + GreenIndex] = 0xBE;
                    convertedDepthBits[i32 + BlueIndex] = 0xC0;
                    convertedDepthBits[i32 + 3] = 0x66;
                }
                else
                {
                    convertedDepthBits[i32 + RedIndex] = 0x0;
                    convertedDepthBits[i32 + GreenIndex] = 0x0;
                    convertedDepthBits[i32 + BlueIndex] = 0x0;
                    convertedDepthBits[i32 + 3] = 0x0;
                }
            }

            if (silhouette == null || haveNewFormat)
            {
                silhouette = new WriteableBitmap(
                    depthFrame.Width,
                    depthFrame.Height,
                    96,
                    96,
                    PixelFormats.Bgra32,
                    null);

                SilhouetteImage.Source = silhouette;
            }

            silhouette.WritePixels(
                new Int32Rect(0, 0, depthFrame.Width, depthFrame.Height),
                convertedDepthBits,
                depthFrame.Width * Bgra32BytesPerPixel,
                0);

            Silhouette = silhouette;

            this.lastImageFormat = depthFrame.Format;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: yes it exactly is what i want! thanks so much, i will keep on doing the job :)

Comment: @Evil Closet Monkey, is it possible to add extra joints for the skeleton? For example, if a man is holding a stick then the skeleton will add one extra joint representing the stick? If you could please let me know if there is any solution to solve this?